# How to change the price used for price filter and sorting?

Tags: price, layered-navigation, sorting

I have a problem with the Layered Navigation and sorting in the categories.

For both Magento seems not to use the normal price of the product (see examples below).

Product "Test 2" has an option which adds 100 € to the price

Product "Test 1" has no option.

The sort order in the image should be descending (price). As you see it is not. Also there is a price-range 0-99.99 and one from 100.00 to higher. Which is obviously not correct.

Category with filter and sort order:
http://www.directupload.net/file/d/4062/orx5ynpx_png.htm

It seems that magento adds options in the product to the price and use it for filter and sorting. But I want magento to use the price shown in category instead.

Can anyone help me were I can find the calculation-method for the price and how I can change it so it uses the normal price without options for filter and sorting?

(Magento 1.9.2.0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for my problem:
To every option I add a row with price = 0 €. This way the problem doesn't appear.

Seams as if Magento only uses the cheapest option in its calculation.